# Concatenate result dataframe after multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, windows, dataframe, multiprocessing

I wrote `multitprocessing` program in python. For each process my program returns a `dataframe`. At the end I want to `concatenate` those dataframes into one dataframe. How can I do it?

Code example:

```
def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        result_df = pool.starmap(search, zip(a, b))

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # freeze_support()
    main()
```

Comment: does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621116/combine-dataframes-returned-from-python-multiprocess-calling-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

`df = pd.concat(result_df)`